# How many autoindent tags do we need?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

It seems as though [autoindent](/questions/tagged/autoindent), [auto-indent](/questions/tagged/auto-indent), and [auto-indentation](/questions/tagged/auto-indentation) mean the same thing, and should probably be merged. Maybe some synonyms are in order, but there are maybe 10 people in the world with enough points to make the suggestion.

Comment: I have more suggestions for you (j/k): `[auto-intentation]`, `[auto-tabs]`, `[auto-spaces]`, `[magic-stuff-that-makes-my-code-look-neater]`. I'm especially fond of the last one.

Comment: @Asylum: Don't forget [python]!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, **yes**, for the three you've mentioned.